# nodejs Puppeter no funciona en linux

Tags: nodejs, cpanel, puppeteer

Tengo un servidor que genera pdf perfecto instalado en mi máquina (con windows) pero cuándo lo subo a un servidor linux por cpanel me da este error:

```
App 1888722 output: /home/brasbur4/nodevenv/public_html/Congreso/16/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:348
App 1888722 output:       reject(new Error([
App 1888722 output:              ^
App 1888722 output: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
App 1888722 output: /home/brasbur4/nodevenv/public_html/Congreso/16/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686378/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
App 1888722 output: TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
App 1888722 output:     at onClose (/home/brasbur4/nodevenv/public_html/Congreso/16/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:348:14)
App 1888722 output:     at Interface.<anonymous> (/home/brasbur4/nodevenv/public_html/Congreso/16/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:337:50)
App 1888722 output:     at Interface.emit (node:events:525:35)
App 1888722 output:     at Interface.close (node:readline:590:8)
App 1888722 output:     at Socket.onend (node:readline:280:10)
App 1888722 output:     at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
App 1888722 output:     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
App 1888722 output:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

El código es bastante básico:

```
let  Nombre="Listado-" + Date.now() + ".pdf"
let Archivo= "./public/Listados/"  + Nombre
var content=req.body.html
const convertHTMLToPDF = require("pdf-puppeteer");
convertHTMLToPDF(content,(Archivo)=>{
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  res.send(Archivo);
},({format:'A4'}))
```

Gracias!!!

Comment: consultaste la sección [troubleshooting](https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting) de la documentación oficial de Puppeteer?

Comment: si, pero no encontré respuesta a ese error